# Excel INDEX MATCH when value may be in one of 3 columns

Tags: excel, match

I am using INDEX/MATCH to find values in a single column and return the value from a different column using:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,0))
```

This will search to see if `A2` matches a value in Sheet1 column `B`, and if so will return the value from that row in column `A`.

However, the value that is being searched might actually be in column `B`, `C` or `D` and I would like to be able to search for these values in the same query.

I was hoping that the following would work, but it does not:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$B:$D,0))
```

Is there a way to do this simply without `IF` statements?  I have a version working with 3 columns using an `IF` statement but it seems that there should be a much easier way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly a little convoluted, but something like:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(1,SIGN((A2=Sheet1!$B:$B)+(A2=Sheet1!$C:$C)+(A2=Sheet1!$D:$D)),0))
```

Accomplishes the same thing, although it's an array formula so you will have to enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (also works if the value shows up more than once because it's really just checking for >0)

Comment: A nice alternative, if a little inflexible (imagine if the range being searched were e.g. columns B to Z, not just columns B to D). The bigger issue though is that, by referencing entire columns, that formula is being forced to calculate over more than three million cells,

Comment: I've been playing around with this, and the answer from @XORLX, and I've had greater success so far using this one so far but that might be because I'm struggling to implement the other into my actual data.  Like mentioned in the comment above, the process was horribly slow when using the full ranges, but limiting to `$B$2:$B$800` etc. makes this work as quickly as a VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT, though this requires that the search value occur no more than once within the range:

`=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B1:$D10,A2),INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B1:$D10=A2)*ROW(Sheet1!$B1:$D10))),"No Match")`

If the search value can occur more than once within the range, the solution would depend upon which of those should take precedence when determining the return.

Note that the use of an array-processing function (SUMPRODUCT) means that you would be ill-advised to use entire column references. Unlike e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), such formulas calculate over all cells passed to them, whether technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not.

A suitably low, though sufficient, upper bound should be chosen for the end row reference. Alternatively, you can create dynamic ranges for your data, such that they automatically adjust as that data expands/contracts, thus offering optimal efficiency.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are just returning a number value from column A, you can use:

```
=MAX(IF(A2=Sheet1!$B$2:$D$10,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10))
```

Enter with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**.

If instead you are returning a text value (or a number value) from column A, you can use:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(A2=Sheet1!$B$2:$D$10,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),1))
```

Also needs to be entered with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**.

You can change the ranges as necessary.